# Behat "Unrecognized options"

Tags: php, laravel, behat

I'm trying to run Behat (first time for me) and it worked.

But i have a configuration problem. I tried to change the paths of features and bootstrap like so:

```
#behat.yml
default:
    paths:
        features: app/tests/features
        bootstrap: %behat.paths.features%/bootstrap
```

Now i'm getting an exception:

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException] Unrecognized options "paths" under "testwork"
```

What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Behat 3 is out by now. You configure paths as follows:

```
#behat.yml
default:
  autoload:
    '': %paths.base%/tests/features/bootstrap
  suites:
    default:
      paths:
        - %paths.base%/tests/features
```

The path given in the `autoload` section sets the path where Behat looks for context classes. The paths in the `suites` section are where the feature definitions (of the `default` suite in this case) live in.

Comment: Current behat documentation is allways pointing to 2.5 [2014-10-06]. So, here is cached version: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:TZwjd-kcKH0J:docs.behat.org/en/latest/guides/5.suites.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk

Comment: Current Behat documentation does not even mention the "autoload" setting at all. http://docs.behat.org/en/latest/guides/5.suites.html

Comment: Behat 3 documentation: [custom autoloading](http://docs.behat.org/en/v3.0/guides/6.profiles.html#custom-autoloading), [suite paths](http://docs.behat.org/en/v3.0/guides/5.suites.html#suite-paths)

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to use Behat 3, which is not released yet - use version 2.5 instead.